# What protection menchanism are used to protect binaries from decompilation in commercial software?

Tags: decompiling

I'm wondering to what extend one can get source code from binaries and what can be done to protect it's content. Especially I'm interested if expensive commercial software like e.g. CAD systems or ERP systems use such protection.

I know that decompilation can give you assembler code and from that you can get an idea of what e.g. C or C++ code looks like. I also know that there will be no function or variable names, hence data structures will look very different.

But are additional protection mechanism applied to expensive software?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do much with the disassembled code of any application, so only important stuff that's worth to hid gets some protection effort.

That can be reduced to:

- Algorithms (Even though many algorithms come from academy research, you don't want your competition to know which one you're using).
- DRM enforcement related code.
- Embedded devices, were you don't deal with consumer piracy, but with hardware clones.
- Malware and backdoors.

If you control in some way the hardware using the code (like with UEFI chain of trust, or with embedded devices) to some extent you may control how the code is used. In that case, encryption of the code is an alternative, where the keys are stored somewhere of difficult access on the hardware.

Otherwise, the only deterrent you have is code obfuscation.